# What is a correct IP4 CIDR for AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, cidr

I am trying to create some new subnets and cannot get AWS to accept a CIDR IP4.
I receive the message: Must be valid IPv4 CIDR. Nothing I try is accepted.
What is a valid IP4 for this purpose, and why? See attached image>
[image]

I tried :

- 10.0.0.1/16
- 10.0.1.0/16
- 10.1.0.0/16
- 10.0.0.255/16
- 10.255.255.255/16
- 128.128.128.128/16
- 10.0.0.16/24
- 10.0.0.14/24
  ... this list goes on a bit.
  I also tried various CIDR calculators online which didn't give me a correct subnet IP4.
  Obviously without understanding what i'm being asked to input trying random numbers is useless. I also read the documentation on amazon, which made no sense to me, hence me asking this question.
  Can someone answer what they would enter in this box, so that I can understand by example?

Comment: try to create 10.0.0.0/24 for example.

Comment: @batistuta09 aaah i see! please put your answer as an answer so that I can mark it the correct solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create subnet, which is in range 10.0.0.0/16 .

For example:

10.0.0.0/24

10.2.0.128/25

etc

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR version** ([Amazon VPC FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/))

- Read about [CIDR Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) to understand what the below means.
- AWS VPC CIDR block size must be between `/16` and `/28`, e.g. `192.168.0.0/16`
- Subnet CIDR block sizes must also be between `/16` and `/28` and in reality should have smaller CIDR blocks than the VPC because you typically want more than one subnet per VPC. E.g. `192.168.2.0/24`
- The *host-part* of the CIDR must be zero'ed. I.e. this is valid: `192.168.0.0/16` and this isn't: `192.168.2.123/16`
- Choose a block from [RFC1918 private range addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918): `10.0.0.0/8`, `172.16.0.0/12`, or `192.168.0.0/16` unless you really really know what you are doing.

---

**Some explanation:**

In IPv4 and IPv6 we sort of distinguish between **network** and **host** addresses. Hosts belong to networks, smaller networks belong to larger networks.

In case of IPv4 a *host address* looks like this: `192.168.2.123` - it's got 4 bytes which means 32 bits (1 byte = 8 bits).

[**CIDR notation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) is the standard way to describe network addresses. It uses a prefix notation to split the address to a **network part** and a **host part** where the prefix can be anywhere between `/0` and `/32`, showing the number of *bits* from the left that are known.

A **host address** has all the 32 bits defined. That means our example instance address in CIDR notation can be written as `192.168.2.123/32` - we know all the bits.

This instance perhaps sits in a subnet `192.168.2.0/24` - 24 bits (= 3 bytes) from the left (`192.168.2`) are the CIDR block of the subnet, while the remaining 8 bits on the right are available for hosts.

Network addresses are hierarchical - **VPC** has a *large* network address block with **subnets** inside having *smaller* slices of the VPC network network address block. That means your VPC CIDR block can be for example `192.168.0.0/16` - the first 16 bits (`192.168`) is defined and *everything* in the VPC must have addresses that start with `192.168.`: subnets, instances, RDS, load balancers, everything.

**So to wrap up:** an instance IP `192.168.2.123` (`/32`) belongs to subnet CIDR `192.168.2.0/24` which belongs to VPC CIDR `192.168.0.0/16`. The *undefined bits* in the subnet and VPC addrs are always set to `0`.

However the prefix lengths don't have to be aligned to bytes boundaries. This would also be a valid example: instance IP `192.168.2.123` (`/32`) belongs to subnet CIDR `192.168.2.64/26` which belongs to VPC CIDR `192.168.2.0/23`. It's a bit more effort to work it out but it's completely valid.

Hope that helps :)